How to create a subset of elements in multiple data frames that are greater than elements in a different list?
Sorry if I formatted this incorrectly or if the title isn't quite right, I am new to R and stack overflow. I am working with a list (called climates) that has 20 data frames (from each province) that each have year, month, day, and temperature columns (along with some other stuff). I am looking to find the rows where the temperature is above a certain threshold, but this threshold changes for each province. I've been able to use lapply to find the threshold for each province, but when I try to use those thresholds to find the rows in the data where the temp is above the threshold, the output isn't correct. My code does return a bunch of numbers, but they don't seem to be related to being greater than the threshold, and I also don't know how to get it to return the entire row instead of just the temperature value.
example climate list:
A <- data.frame("D" = c(1:30), "T" = c(sample(10:30, size = 30, replace = TRUE)))
B <- data.frame("D" = c(1:30), "T" = c(sample(4:22, size = 30, replace = TRUE)))
C <- data.frame("D" = c(1:30), "T" = c(sample(14:35, size = 30, replace = TRUE)))

climate <- list("Alist" = A, "Blist" = B, "Clist" = C)
climate

I've used lapply to find the threshold,
thresh95 <- lapply(lapply(
  climate, `[[`, 2), # this one takes my list of climate data and selects the T column for all provinces
  quantile, probs = c(0.95), na.rm = TRUE) # this one takes the previous list and finds 95th percentile value
thresh95

but when I try to then find the temperatures that are above the threshold, something goes wrong.
tmax95 <-  lapply(lapply(climate, `[[`, 2), # this one takes my list of climate data and selects the T column for all provinces
  function(x) x[which(x>thresh95)])# this one takes my list of climate data and selects the temps that are greater than the threshold
tmax95

Is there a way to write something that will return a subset of each province's data frame where the condition is that the temperature is greater than the threshold? Thanks!

Be careful naming your variables 'T' since R may interpret that as TRUE in certain situations.

You need mapply.
But first, always set the seed when simulating data.
set.seed(1234)

A <- data.frame("D" = c(1:30), "T" = c(sample(10:30, size = 30, replace = TRUE)))
B <- data.frame("D" = c(1:30), "T" = c(sample(4:22, size = 30, replace = TRUE)))
C <- data.frame("D" = c(1:30), "T" = c(sample(14:35, size = 30, replace = TRUE)))


mapply(\(x,y) x[which(x[,2] > y),], x=climate, y=thresh95, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)


$Alist
    D  T
19 19 30

$Blist
[1] D T
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$Clist
    D  T
17 17 35


Thanks so much! What does setting the seed mean?

You used the sample function, which generates random data. It helps others to reproduce your and my results. Without set.seed(), we'd all get different results.

What's Wrong?
Your thres95 is a list like
> thresh95
$Alist
95%
 29

$Blist
95%
 22

$Clist
95%
 34

but x is just a vector. So you have error if you apply x > thresh95
Workaround Option
You can run the code below (data borrowed from @Edward)
lapply(
  climate,
  function(x) {
    subset(
      x,
      T > quantile(T, probs = 0.95)
    )
  }
)

which gives
$Alist
    D  T
19 19 30

$Blist
[1] D T
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$Clist
    D  T
17 17 35


Very clever. You realised that there's no need to create thresh95. ;)

@Edward haha, I am just a fan of short codes.
